# SU(2) subgroups of SU(4)?

Tags: group-theory

The Wikipedia article on [Gell-Mann matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices) states that there are 3 independent SU(2) subgroups of SU(3). One of them, for example, is given by the generators $\{ \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 \}$, which satisfy the commutation relation of the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ algebra.

How can I found similar subgroups of SU(4) such that their combination satisfy a commutation relation of the form $[t_a, t_b] = \epsilon_{abc} t_c$ as well?

So far I am aware of three such ways -  for example the matrices A, B and B, where $B= i( t_2 + t_{14}) $, $C= i(t_5 - t_{12})$ and $D= i (t_7 +  t_{10})$ and $t_i$ are the 4x4 generators of SU(4), obey the above commutation relation.

Are there any more independent ways?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/118484 http://mathoverflow.net/a/65530 Do you have a physical motivation for looking at $\mathrm{SU}(4)$? If not, I think this would be better suited at math.SE.

Comment: Yes, we are looking at higher dimensional gauge theories (color electrodynamics). I was actually aware of that question and I have checked all the suggested references - unfortunately most of them are a bit too involved and general (in the case of SU(N), I might have to go that route), but I was hoping this question had already been addressed within the context of SU(4) gauge theories.

Comment: While there are many pretty results about $\mathrm{SU}(N)$ gauge theories, I know not about such subgroup results. If you were searching for the maximal torus or a similarly "special" subgroup, there are methods, I think, but I can't see anything special about $\mathrm{SU}(2) \subset \mathrm{SU}(4)$. Is there?

Comment: I guess it is only "special" in the sense that since there is a n x n matrix representation of SU(2) for any n, it becomes possible to obtain isotropic theories out of any SU(n) gauge by mapping SU(n) subalgebras into SU(2) (at least we've been able to do that up to SU(4)).

Comment: There's the generalized Gell-Mann Matrices: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4100876/202425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dynkin diagram of $SU(4)$ has 3 nodes, which means that it carries three elements in it's Cartan subalgebra. Consider those as three possible choices for $J_z$. Each of those can be attached with a pair of raising/lowering operators $J_{\pm}$ -- to create one $SU(2)$ algebra each.

EDIT:

BTW, a simple way to see this is the following: Consider the generators on the diagonal (you'll have $N-1$ independent ones, due to the tracelessness condition) as the $J_z$. Then, the corresponding $J_\pm$ are those generators that are one step off-diagonal above/below, and there are exactly $N-1$ of them.

---

I presume that argument can be translated to a statement about groups, but I don't think I'm equipped to do that.

Comment: I'll look into Dynkin diagram, thanks. Do you think this could be generalized to arbitrary SU(N) groups?

Comment: Yes, an arbitrary $SU(N)$ group has $N-1$ such nodes, and hence as many independent $SU(2)$s sitting inside. In some sense, that is an essential part of the approach to classifying lie algebras. Since I know that you're a physicist, take a look here:http://phyweb.lbl.gov/~rncahn/www/liealgebras/book.html

Comment: Them what about SU(3)? I get three independent subgroups (see the Gell-Mann matrices article), yet only 2 nodes. Or are they not quite related? Anyway, I'll look more into it, thanks for the ref. above.

Comment: IMHO: If I understand that link correctly, it is extending my statement by a little bit. Eg: think of the meson octet (representation of $SU(3)$. The two $J_3$ generators I mentioned are the $\hat{i}$ and $-\frac{1}{2} \hat{i} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \hat{j}$ on that diagram. In the language of the Wiki article, (for reasons I do not understand) it also includes the third possible generator $-\frac{1}{2} \hat{i} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \hat{j}$ as "independent" (even though those three are no linearly independent). To me, the sense in which those $SU(3)$ groups are "independent" depends on context.

Comment: Siva, I have a couple more questions if you are still reading this, especially after taking a closer look at the write up.

In your answer, you mention a way to find the corresponding J±  given Jz. I'm not seeing this for SU(3), for example. Say I pick Lambda 8 (eight Gell-Mann matrix). How do I infer the corresponding raising/lowering operators from that to form an SU(2)?

Comment: Also, looking at equation II.3 in the notes above, and picking Y as our diagonal matrix, would the associated matrices be U_x and U_y? And is there a more systematic way to determine the coefficients to combine them to form SU(2)?

Comment: An easy way to think about it is as follows: You can do a basis transformation to change $\lambda_8$ to $\lambda_3$. Then it's straightforward how you can generate $J_{\pm}$ from $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Comment: Do you mean, rotating $\lambda_8$ into $\lambda_3$, as in $ M^{-1} \lambda_8 M = \lambda_3$? It seems that such a matrix $M$ does not exist.

Comment: For reference, I'm using the matrices as specified [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices). I don't have the time right now to completely work out the details, but I've [sketched out my expectations](http://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~siva/files/SU3-expected.pdf) and those might help you verify. Let me know if it works out. Think of the [eight-fold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_%28physics%29) at the back of your mind, when seeing the diagram.

Comment: Ah so I guess I was wrong when I thought I could find another independant su(2) that involved generators other than $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$, correct? Am I thinking right if I say that to obtain the second, independent su(2) that contains $\lambda_8$, it will contain some combination of $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ as well (I'll work out the coef eventually, just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly)?

Comment: It must contain some of $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$, since the eightfold-way multiplet diagram shows that the creation operators in the two directions are not orthogonal.

Comment: Last question: is it correct to say that two independent su(2) can be given by (1.11) and (1.12) from https://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/theoreticalphysics/public/MSc/PartSymm/SU%283%29Notes.pdf ? cheers

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I meant. (Those notes are quite comprehensive!) BTW, I think that in my hurry I made a typo in my sketch (I think the bottom right corner of my PDF must contain $\lambda_8$ instead of $\lambda_3$ and a missing $\pm$). That gives you the "second" SU(2). Note that the way I worded my answer, the three SU(2)s are not linearly independent.