# What is meant here, when it is said that "diagonal generalized Gell-Mann matrices are not unique"?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, physics

According to [the answer given here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/8478/generalized-gell-mann-matrices/), the diagonal generalized Gell-Mann matrices are not unique.  But what exactly is meant by this?

- Are they just saying that we can multiply the diagonal matrices by a constant and still have a valid generator of the group since the matrices will still be orthogonal? If so, then why are the other generalized Gell-Mann matrices not also being called non-unique (you can multiply them by a constant and still have an orthogonal set of matrices).
- Or are they saying that we could have completely different diagonal matrices as long as they are traceless and satisfy orthogonality under the Hilbert-Schmidt norm: $(A,B) =Tr(AB)$ ? For example we could have $\textrm{diag}(1 ,0 , -1)$ and $\textrm{diag}( 1/\sqrt{3} , -2/\sqrt{3} , 1/\sqrt{3})$, or even something more radically different such as $\textrm{diag}(a,b,c)$ and $\textrm{diag}(d,e,f)$ where none of $a,b,c$ are $0$?

Comment: I would guess the poster meant your second option.

Comment: @user17945 But if that's true, they're not really Gell-Mann matrices are they?

Comment: Gell-Mann was only looking for a basis of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ (or actually, its complexification, which is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$). I don't think there's any universal standard for the higher-dimensional versions (spanning $\mathfrak{sl}(d,\mathbb{C})$), despite the wikipedia page linked in the sagemath answer. In particular, the choice of diagonal matrices seems somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: @user17945 But then aren't the non-diagonal matrices "arbitrary" too? Also the 4x4 matrices are quite universal too (pg. 368): https://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/science_and_technology/physics/quantum_mechanics/Quantum%20Mechanics%20-%20Symmetries%202nd%20ed.%20-%20W.%20Greiner,%20B.%20Muller.pdf

Comment: Sure, the off-diagonal matrices are arbitrary, but it makes sense to have as few non-zero entries as possible, so in this sense the given ones are the most natural. For the diagonal entries, however, there isn't as obvious a choice. In mathematics it would be more common to take each diagonal basis element to have one 1 and one -1 (as in $\lambda_3$), but Gell-Mann took a different convention. I'm not really sure what you're looking for here - there are various conventions one could adopt, and no real "canonical" one, which is all that the poster in your link meant.

Comment: There's multiple choices for the off-diagonal matrices that have the same number of non-zero entries, for example instead of putting the Pauli $x$ matrix in the top-left corner of a 3x3 matrix (as Gell-Mann did), you can put it in the bottom-right corner, but Gell-Mann seems to have used a specific algorithm which I have outlined in my answer, which does not leave room for "choices" anywhere (everything is determined by the algorithm). Specifically for the diagonal matrices, if you put the Pauli $z$ matrix in the top-left corner like Gell-Mann did, then you have only one choice for the rest.

Comment: Huh? The matrix with Pauli $x$ matrix in the bottom-right corner is what Gell-Mann calls $\lambda_6$, so I don't see what you mean by this being forced rather than a choice. Of course you can come up with several specific methods for deriving a basis, but there's nothing really "canonical" about any of them. Again, you asked what the poster in the sagemath answer meant by saying there is no unique generalisation of the Gell-Mann matrices, and I told you my interpretation of this statement. If you disagree, then I don't know what further I can say.

Comment: I meant bottom-left. Furthermore, I'm not the user that posted this question, I'm the user that posted the answer. Also, no one used the word "canonical".

Answer (score 4):

**If deriving the n×n matrices in the same way Gell-Mann did, there is only one choice for the diagonal matrices.**

Gell-Mann generated the two diagonal 3×3 matrices by starting with the Pauli $z$ matrix and padding it with zeros to make it 3×3, and letting the other diagonal matrix be arbitrary:

$$\tag{1}
\lambda_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \lambda_8=\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & 0\\
0 & 0 & c \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then he used the following constraints:

\begin{eqnarray}
\textrm{Tr}(\lambda_3\lambda_8) = 0 \tag{2}\\
\textrm{Tr}(\lambda_8) = 0 \tag{3}\\
\textrm{Tr}(\lambda_8^2) = 2 .\tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}

**The first constraint forces us to choose $b = a$, 

the second constraint forces us to choose $c = -2a$, 

and the third constraint forces us to choose $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.**

Let's now derive the three diagonal 4×4 matrices in the same, way, by starting with the 3×3 matrices padded with zeros, and adding an arbitrary diagonal matrix:

$$\tag{5}
\Lambda_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \Lambda_8=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \Lambda_{15} = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & d \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then we have the following constraints:

\begin{eqnarray}
\textrm{Tr}(\Lambda_3\Lambda_{15}) = 0 \tag{6}\\
\textrm{Tr}(\Lambda_8\Lambda_{15}) = 0 \tag{7}\\
\textrm{Tr}(\Lambda_{15}) = 0 \tag{8}\\
\textrm{Tr}(\Lambda_{15}^2) = 2 .\tag{9}
\end{eqnarray}

**The first constraint forces us to choose $b = a$

The second constraint forces us to choose $c = a$

The third constraint forces us to choose $d = -3a$

The fourth constraint forces us to choose $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.**

This matches when you see on Pg 368 of [this book (PDF)](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/science_and_technology/physics/quantum_mechanics/Quantum%2520Mechanics%2520-%2520Symmetries%25202nd%2520ed.%2520-%2520W.%2520Greiner,%2520B.%2520Muller.pdf&source=gmail&ust=1618421530671000&usg=AFQjCNHajxT7CKH8uujPMbsWx-tt-MTABw), Eq. 11 of [this paper (PDF)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1174.pdf), Pg 7 of [this talk (PDF)](http://mathserver.neu.edu/%7Eramras/Tapas2010/Chase3Notes10.pdf), Eq 3 of [this paper (PDF)](http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv10i28p9.pdf), and the definition of "generalized Gell-Mann matrices" given [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedGell-MannMatrix.html).

In general we carry over padded versions of the $n-2$ diagonal matrices from the $(n-1)$×$(n-1)$ case, and the orthogonality conditions force us to make all entries of the last diagonal matrix to be equal except for the last entry. The last entry $x$ has to be the negative of the sum of the rest of the entries (which are all the same, call them $a$ so $x = -(n-1)a$), due to the condition that the matrices are all traceless. The condition that the trace of each matrix multiplied by itself is 2, gives us only one choice for $a$.