# Can you use a tensor product of SU(2)xSU(2) to identify the three SU(2) subgroups of SU(4)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

[SU(4) has three SU(2) subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009722/su2-subgroups-of-su4), so can we use the fact that SU(2)$\otimes$SU(2)$\subset$SU(4) to identify two of these three subgroups?

For example, in the defining representation of SU(4) as 4$\times$4 unitary matrices of determinant one we can identify the subgroup SU(2)$\otimes$SU(2) via the following:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & -\bar{\beta}\\
\beta & \bar{\alpha}
\end{pmatrix} \otimes 
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & -\bar{\delta}\\
\delta & \bar{\gamma}
\end{pmatrix}
= \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \alpha  \gamma  & - \alpha  \bar{\delta} & -\bar{\beta} \gamma  & \bar{\beta} \bar{\delta} \\
 \alpha  \delta  & \alpha  \bar{\gamma} & -\bar{\beta} \delta  & -\bar{\beta} \bar{\gamma} \\
 \beta  \gamma  & - \beta  \bar{\delta} & \bar{\alpha} \gamma  & -\bar{\alpha} \bar{\delta} \\
 \beta \delta & \beta  \bar{\gamma} & \bar{\alpha} \delta  & \bar{\alpha} \bar{\gamma} \\
\end{array}
\right) \in \rm{SU(4)}
\end{equation}

for $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$, same for $\gamma,\delta$.

If $\gamma=1,\delta=0$ and $\beta=0$ then the group element is $\rm{diag}(e^{i \phi},e^{i \phi},e^{-i \phi},e^{-i \phi})$ for $\phi = \rm{arg}(\alpha)$. Similarly if $\alpha=1,\beta=0$ and $\gamma=0$ then the group element is $\rm{diag}(e^{i \theta},e^{-i \theta},e^{i \theta},e^{-i \theta})$ for $\theta = \rm{arg}(\gamma)$. The last SU(2) subgroup in this case may be found from the diagonal embedding of $U(1)$ as $\rm{diag}(e^{i \varphi},e^{-i \varphi},e^{-i \varphi},e^{i \varphi})$ and the corresponding other group actions to make this a full SU(2). This gives us three SU(2) subgroups in SU(4).

However, I have seen other people describe the SU(2) subgroup's as the spin 1/2 representation acting on the first two elements of a column vector, spin 1 representation acting on the first three elements of a column vector, and spin 3/2 representation acting on all four elements of a column vector.

Here are my questions: are these two descriptions of the SU(2) subgroups equally valid? Furthermore, does it matter that the three SU(2) subgroups I've identified are all reducible to a spin 1/2 representation (i.e. the $2\times2$ defining representation of SU(2) )?

If it helps the context is a tensor product of two qubits, and local vs entangling actions.

Comment: That question and answer is imprecise. There are infinitely many different subgroups isomorphic to $SU(2)$ with $SU(n)$ for $n \ge 3$, just take one and conjugate it around wildly. Maybe they mean ones whose maximal torus is contained in a chosen maximal torus of the big group, that's what the Dynkin diagram approach suggests to me at least. Although even then strictly speaking there are infinitely many choices.

Comment: We don't normally define tensor products for groups (except for abelian groups). From what I can tell you mean the set of Kronecker products of the matrices. But this is simply isomorphic to the direct product. So you have found a different embedding of $SU(2) \times SU(2) \subset SU(4)$ but I suspect this is just conjugate to the usual one $(A,B) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{pmatrix}$ which is easier to work with.